# Earning money with QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, license

I have developed a QGIS plugin that is useful for many people and it reduces a day-long workflow to a few minutes. I have ideas for other plugins too. To continue to add value to QGIS and save the time of other users, I would like to know if I can earn money through QGIS plugins.

Can we put pop-ups in the plugin that every now and then ask for user feedback and if they like the plugin then ask them for donation or is there a better way than this to raise money through the QGIS plugins?

Comment: you can but people can edit them back out again :-)

Comment: 1. That is why I am looking for a better way than this.
2. I don't mind if people edit the code or they don't want to donate, but some pople might donate if the plugin is really adding value to their work.

Comment: Most are donate to fund a plugin, SLYR is a great example of a purchased QGIS plugin https://north-road.com/slyr/

Comment: To clarify how slyr works with the GPL requirement of a qgis plugin: the actual slyr tool is split into two components. The lower level one is not open source, and handles all the parsing of lyr/mxd files. This component doesn't use any qgis libraries (or other GPL licensed code). On top of this sits a GPL qgis plugin layer -- which imports the closed source module when is available (ie, licensed). Without the underlying non GPL module the plugin is of very limited use. This approach only works if you can cleanly split your plugins functionality into a layer which doesn't use QGIS/GPL licenses

Comment: @ndawson Thanks for clarification on SLYR plugin. Can you also reply to the pop up part of my question. Since I will be just asking for a donation (not forcing it through licensing) I think this should be okay.